# Wininet - How to download and verify SSL certificate

Tags: windows, winapi, ssl, ssl-certificate, wininet

I want to download and verify certificate just like Internet Explorer, i tried to monitor IE API calls to see how its doing it all.
First of all i don't see which wininet function is downloading the SSL certificate and secondly there are many calls to crypt32.dll functions.

Someone can tell me which functions request the certificate or the certificate data needed to verify the certificate.
I want to understand the methodology and to implement exactly the same behavior in my application.

Answer (score 1):

> Someone can tell me which functions request the certificate

Certificate is part of SSL handshake, it is not downloaded separately.

Comment: Well how its check if the certificate is valid ?

Answer (score 0):

If you open an https connection with WinINet it will download and check the certificate for you.  So it's not really clear what you're trying to do.

If you want to inspect the certificate downloaded by WinINet you can use [INTERNET_OPTION_SERVER_CERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/06/05/understanding-the-new-wininet-option-internet-option-server-cert-chain-context.aspx) in IE8 or later.

If you don't want to use WinINet you can use an [existing implementation](http://www.openssl.org/) of [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) or you can implement it yourself, but the latter isn't a good idea.

Comment: No one knows exactly which Crypto API's are used to confirm is the certificate verified ?

Comment: I don't know exactly which API is used, maybe [CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377163%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Why do you care?